# NSLayout constraint working in iPhone6 but not in lower versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a weird problem with Autolayout. I have set up a NSLayoutConstraint as IBOutlet in order to be able to change it runtime and make a button disappear. It works perfectly in the simulator for iPhone6 but when i choose and iPhone5 or lower it stops working.

The code is the following:

```
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *deleteConfirmTrailing;
...
@synthesize deleteConfirmTrailing = _deleteConfirmTrailing;

 - (IBAction)cellButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == _deleteMessageButton)
    {
        NSLog(@"delete button pressed");

        _deleteConfirmTrailing.constant = 40;

    }
...
```

But this does not work as I said in iPhone5 or lower. Any idea?

Comment: try calling [self.view layoutSubviews] after changing constraint

Comment: In your method `cellButtonClicked`, add `NSParameterAssert(_deleteConfirmTrailing);` as first line. If it crashes, you are not setting your IBOutlet properly.

Comment: None of these suggestions worked. Had to set [self layoutSubviews] as I am subclassing a UITableViewCell but no effect. Also NSParameterAssert worked just fine with no crash and it would have been strange because it works when using the iPhone 6 simulator.